# PHP Arrays With Embedded Pieces Pointing to Previous Piece

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to merge the following arrays with each piece pointing to the preceding piece and where there is duplication it builds an embedded array, see my desired array:

Arrays:

```
array ('test.php'),
array ('test', 'test.php'),
array ('test', 'test1'),
array ('test', 'test1', 'test1.php'),
array ('test', 'test.php'),
array ('test', 'test2', 'test2.php'),
array ('test', 'test2', 'test3.php'),
array ('test', 'test2', 'test4.php')
```

Desired Array:

```
Array 
    (
        [0] => test.php
        [1] => Array
        ( 
            [test] => Array 
            (
                [0] => test.php
                [1] => Array 
                ( 
                    [test1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => test1.php
                    )
                )

                [2] => test.php
                [3] => Array
                (
                    [test2] => Array (
                    
                        [0] => test2.php
                        [1] => test3.php
                        [2] => test4.php
                    )
                )
            )
        )
   )
```

I appreciate any help anyone can give in advance.

Comment: Can there be more or less than 4 arrays? Are all the arrays generated at the same time, or in a loop? It would be helpful to see the code that generates the arrays to help give you the best answer.

Comment: Yes, there can be an unlimited amount of arrays. I am basically creating a site map and so I am using the URLs of multiple files and splitting them into their parts using explode. I then want previous directories pointing to all the files within the directory. The arrays are created as I loop through each file and explode its parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume that your source arrays are always sorted from root to the value I can offer you the following solution

```
<?php
    function merge (array $src, array $dst) {
        if (!$src || empty($src)) {
            return $dst;
        }

        $tempDst = &$dst;
    
        foreach ($src as $srcItem) {
            $itemIsSet  = false;
        
            if (preg_match('/(.php)/', $srcItem)) {
                $tempDst[] = $srcItem;
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($tempDst as $key => $value) {
                if (is_array($value) && isset($value[$srcItem])) {
                    $tempDst = &$tempDst[$key][$srcItem];
                    $itemIsSet = true;
                    break;
                } 
            }


            if (!$itemIsSet) {
                array_push($tempDst, array(
                    $srcItem => array()
                ));

                $last = array_key_last($tempDst);
                $tempDst = &$tempDst[$last][$srcItem];
            }
        }

        return $dst;
    }

    $source = array(
        array ('test0.php'),
        array ('test', 'test.php'),
        array ('test', 'test1'),
        array ('test', 'test1', 'test1.php'),
        array ('test', 'test2', 'test2.php'),
        array ('test', 'test2', 'test3.php'),
        array ('test', 'test2', 'test4.php'),
    );

    $destination = array();

    foreach ($source as $array) {
        $destination = merge($array, $destination);
    }
?>
<pre>
    <?= print_r($destination); ?>
</pre>
```

And hier is example output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test0.php
    [1] => Array(
        [test] => Array(
            [0] => test.php
            [1] => Array(
                [test1] => Array(
                    [0] => test1.php
                )
            )
            [2] => Array(
                [test2] => Array(
                    [0] => test2.php
                    [1] => test3.php
                    [2] => test4.php
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: This is so great. I made one mistake however. Is it possible to make the output look like this instead?
`Array  ( [0] => test.php [1] => Array ( [test] => Array ( [0] => test.php [1] => Array ( [test1] => Array ( [0] => test1.php ) [1] => test.php [2] => Array ( [test2] => Array ( [0] => test2.php [1] => test3.php [2] => test4.php ))))))`

Comment: are you mean that the items should be ordered

Comment: No, can you see my edited question? It is easier to see the difference there.

Comment: I decided to loop through the array and if the key wasn't numeric, I put it in an array. Then I put each piece back in a new array. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Dustin - just in case I changed the code in order to produce desired output